# Is it possible to simulate a high index of refraction

Tags: speed-of-light, refraction

I am trying to demonstrate the effect of index of refraction on light speed to a high school class. As with all adolescents, if a story does not have extreme impact, it does not register (hence the need for fires, explosions, destruction in science class). With the velocity of light, we know that light speed is c/n where n is index of refraction. I want to make a video of what it would be like to swim in a liquid with n=3x10^9. Conceptually, the light from an object 1 meter away would reach the eye in 10 seconds.So if someone decided to smack their head with their hand(Covering the distance in 1 second), they would only see the start of the hand moving 10 secs after they felt the slap. But when the hand has reached a minuscule distance away from their face(about 1 second after they started moving their hand), the time differential between the visual cue and the sense of impact would also be minuscule.

So from the moment they felt the impact, they should see a hand moving away from their face as earlier and earlier light wavefronts reach their eyes. Is this logic correct? Can i just take a video of someone slapping their face and run it backwards?

(I cant wait to do this so I can see how many of them will start slapping their heads).

Comment: And I know there are a few smart - alecs in the class who will raise the possibility of dark matter. If the density of dark matter is so great in a region of space where it slows down light so much, that might be the same as a super high index of refraction. So would the galaxies seen through dark matter be made of light that was much ‘older’ than the light that just missed the blob of dark matter? So the dark matter would allow us to look further into the past and so because of Hubble expansion, these galaxies would appear closer?

Comment: This isn't quite what you're looking for, but you might want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation. It's the equivalent of a sonic boom - a phenomenon that occurs when something exceeds the local speed of sound. If the slapping hand reaches the head before the photons it is reflecting, then you're gonna get some spectacular effects!